# Invoking DOM onmousedown event in a Webbrowser from Visual Basic 6

Tags: dom, browser, vb6, dom-events, ihtmldocument2

I load an HTML document into a WebBrowser Control in Visual Basic 6.

There is a link something

```
<a href="something" onmousedown="return abc(this,'asd', 'AO',null,event)">
```

I want to invoke the onmousedown event programatically from VB

I've tried many things, including

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("a")(i).InvokeMember("MouseDown")
doc.getElementsByTagName("a")(i).RaiseEvent("OnMouseDown")
doc.getElementsByTagName("a")(i).MouseDown
```

but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to do this myself, but this vbcity post contains a description and some sample code for this.  Scroll down to the last post on the first page of the thread.

http://vbcity.com/forums/t/37407.aspx

To boil the above post down to essentials, the members of the forms collection can be iterated to find the button which is then clicked.

```
With Me.WebBrowser1
    For n = 0 To .Document.Forms("formname").Length - 1
        If .Document.Forms("formname").Item(n).Value = "buttonvalue" Then
            .Document.Forms("formname").Item(n).Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next n
End With
```

Replace 'formname' and 'buttonvalue' with appropriate values

Comment: This article is about handling events. OP wants to trigger events, which is exactly opposite.

Comment: GSerg: you are correct - I read the question backwards.  I have updated the answer.  Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Actually, doc.getElementsByID("submitbutton").Click works. However, the only event you can fire from the code with this way is "Click", I think. I cannot fire the mousedown event with this and above mentioned ways.